# Regex for TextField is not working as expected in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I require certain constraints in my project, particularly within the regex, to restrict user input and format it appropriately. These rules are intended for implementation within the TextField component in my Jetpack Compose project.

Rules:

- Zero and Dot cannot be at the start.
- There can only be one dot.
- After the dot, there can only be two digits, and before the dot, there can only be four digits.
- If the user does not enter a dot, they can only input four digits. If they do enter a dot, they can add two digits after it.

Examples: (These examples are provided for reference purposes only.)

- 8956.32 -> Valid
- 45 -> Valid
- 562.2 -> Valid
- 0655 -> Invalid
- 0356.00 -> Invalid
- .003 -> Invalid

I tried belwo code but this is not working as expected.

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val regex = remember { Regex("^(?!0|\\.)(?!.*\\.\\.)\\d{1,4}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$") }

TextField(
                label = R.string.label_days,
                value = text,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                ),
                onValueChange = { days ->
                    if (days.isEmpty() || regex.matches(days)){
                     text = days
                    }
                })
```

Comment: How should a trailing dot be handled?

Comment: If you do not allow the trailing dot, it cannot easily be entered, even when the user intends to add additional digits afterwards. Is that the problem you have?

Comment: Well, *do* allow the trailing dot. You can always remove it afterwards when you process the value. It needs to be allowed in the TextField, though. To allow the dot, use this regex `"^[1-9]\\d{0,3}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$"`

Comment: @Leviathan Tried this but its even not typing a single text in textfiedl after apploing this

Comment: Have you escaped all three backslashes?

Comment: @Leviathan Yes i have done that

Comment: Well, your exact code with the regex replaced by the one I provided runs perfectly fine for me, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will work for your requirement

```kotlin
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val regex = remember { Regex("^(?!0)(?!.*\\.\\..*|\\.$)\\d{0,4}(\\.\\d{0,2})?\$") }
    TextField(
        label = {
            Text(text = "Days")
        },
        value = text,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
        ),
        onValueChange = { days ->
            if (days.isEmpty() || days.matches(regex)) {
                text = days
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Hi, how do you create the Regex where can i learn ? Also can you provide another regex as well where decimal is not rewuired only 4 digit number reuired starting not with zero

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

- Allow only valid input. In this case you also have to allow and handle the trailing dot. Also it is better to use `TextFieldValue` variant of the `TextField` to prevent cursor movement on invalid input.
- Allow any input but indicate when the input is invaid and only accept if it is correct. In this case you don't have to allow the trailing dot.

With the regex pattern by @Leviathan it would look like this:

Option 1:

```
val regex = remember { Regex("^[1-9]\\d{0,3}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$") }
var text by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
}
Row {
    TextField(
//        label = R.string.label_days,
        label = { Text("Days") },
        value = text,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
        ),
        onValueChange = { days: TextFieldValue ->
            if (days.text.isEmpty() || regex.matches(days.text)) {
                text = days
            }
        }
    )
    Button(
        onClick = {},
    ) {
        Text("Always OK")
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
val regex = remember { Regex("^[1-9]\\d{0,3}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$") }
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var isValid by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

Row {
    TextField(
//        label = R.string.label_days,
        label = { Text("Days") },
        value = text,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
        ),
        supportingText = {
            if (!isValid) {
                Text("Invalid input")
            }
        },
        isError = !isValid,
        onValueChange = { days: String ->
            isValid = (days.isEmpty() || regex.matches(days))
            text = days
        }
    )
    Button(
        onClick = {},
        enabled = isValid,
    ) {
        Text("OK")
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appriciate your efforts here. Your answer works for me. But i want to keep it simple and the answer provided by RaviSharma worked for. So just curious to know is there anything wrong with RaviSharma answer because with his provided answer i achieved same behaviour that you question is providing.

Comment: Nothing major, using `TextFieldValue` will prevent cursor movements when regex doesn't match. In the `String` version try entering a full number with dot, like "1234.56", then put cursor in the beginning and type anything. The cursor will move without changing the text. @CODAR747